# Calculating covariance of different classes

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the mean and covariance matrix of a set of given observations. The list of points is a 3-d array with the first dimension representing the class number, the second dimension representing the observation number and the third dimension representing the coordinate number. Though I have been able to calculate the mean, there seems to be some problem with the covariance (right now, I am getting a zero matrix). I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to  rectify it.

```
function [ meanEst, covEst, priorProbEst, classMem ] = estimateParams( trainingSet, classList )
%estimateParams estimate all parameters for each class

numRows = size(trainingSet, 1);
numClasses = max(classList.');
%pointList = zeros(numClasses, numRows, 2);
classMem = zeros(numClasses, 1);

for rowCtr = 1:numRows
    curClass = classList(rowCtr, 1);
    classMem(curClass) = classMem(curClass) + 1;
    pointList(curClass, classMem(curClass), 1) = trainingSet(rowCtr, 1);
    pointList(curClass, classMem(curClass), 2) = trainingSet(rowCtr, 2);
end

meanEst      = zeros(numClasses, 2);
covEst       = zeros(numClasses, 2, 2);
priorProbEst = zeros(numClasses, 1);
tot          = zeros(numClasses, 2);

for classCtr = 1:numClasses
    for pointCtr = 1:classMem(classCtr)
        tot(classCtr, 1) = tot(classCtr, 1) + pointList(classCtr, pointCtr, 1);
        tot(classCtr, 2) = tot(classCtr, 2) + pointList(classCtr, pointCtr, 2);
    end
    meanEst(classCtr, 1) = tot(classCtr, 1) / classMem(classCtr);
    meanEst(classCtr, 2) = tot(classCtr, 2) / classMem(classCtr);

    covEst(classCtr) = cov(pointList(classCtr));
    priorProbEst(classCtr) = classMem(classCtr) / numRows;
end
end
```

Thank you for spending time on this!

Comment: Don't you want to reference which matrix (mxn) you want to calculate the covariance matrix for in each iteration?

Comment: @diophantine I want to calculate the covariance matrix of each class based on their list of points. Since pointList is a 3d array, by specifying the classCtr, I get a simple matrix of observations. I am calling the cov method with these observations as argument. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are complicating things by introducing the 3d `pointList` matrix. You can do it if it feels ok, but somewhere there is your covariance estimation error.

There is no reason to keep your data in a structure like that, since you have the class id per observation (i.e each row in your `trainingSet` has the label from the corresponding line in `classList`). As a result, you can always use logical indexing in `trainingSet` to retrieve data for estimation of `mean` and `cov.` As a rule, the `N x M = observation x variables` data matrix for any estimation/classification task is a convention that always helps, and is consistent with many MATLAB functions.

For example, below I create a random training set (NxM matrix) and label index (K=4 classes in a Nx1 list) and estimate mean and covariance for each, assigning the results in a `Kx2` and `2x2xK` matrices respectively.

```
nPoints = 200; % training set points
nClass = 4; % number of unique classes

% random training set of size nPoints x 2 (coordinates)
classList = randi(nClass, nPoints, 1);
trainingSet = randn(nPoints, 2);

meanEst = zeros(nClass, 2);
covEst = zeros(2, 2, nClass);
for classID = 1:nClass
    meanEst(classID,:) = mean(trainingSet(classList==classID,:));
    covEst(:,:,classID) = cov(trainingSet(classList==classID,:));
end
```

As a proof, running your code will produce the same `mean` results as the above example.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use effectively the == operator in Matlab. I have verified it and it is working perfectly.